# Parse WSDL Xml in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, wsdl, xml-parsing

> --uuid:03d866ca-659b-4a58-a460-0552c692d105+id=6 Content-ID: http://tempuri.org/0 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Content-Type:
>   application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
>
> 515e8205-90f4-4284-a40f-3ecd1d8deb6cSeattleUnited
>   States11111WA456
>   Corp
>   AvenueContosobrian_1@contoso.combrian_1@contoso.comBrianSeattleUnited
>   States11111WA123
>   Main
>   StreetJohnsonDavid425-555-0120425-555-0110SeattleUnited
>   States11111WA456
>   Corp
>   AvenueContosobrian_1@contoso.combrian_1@contoso.comBrianSeattleUnited
>   States11111WA123
>   Main
>   StreetJohnsonDavid425-555-0120425-555-0110SUCCESS_ACK
>   --uuid:03d866ca-659b-4a58-a460-0552c692d105+id=6--

This is what I am getting in response of a xml....
I can not parse this wsdl xml...
Can anyone help me?

Comment: good question @dimple panchal :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [SudzC](http://sudzic.com), it will generate WS client for you with all the parsing. All you will have to do is only to manage the object it returns.